# Запись с микрофона C# Linux

Tags: c#, linux, аудио, naudio

может кто работал с этим, имеются ли какие-то библиотеки под .NET для работы с аудио на Linux. И если кто работал с NAudio, работает ли он сейчас под Linux, ответ на этот вопрос (- нет) встречается на форумах достаточно давно, а актуальную информацию найти не удалось

Comment: Возможно naudio работает, разработчик naudio говорит в 2012 следующее: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13796676/17025310, в конце он добавил "я скоро исправлю это", думаю, Вам стоит попробовать, вдруг исправил, всё таки не мало времени прошло. Однако, в некоторых issue на гитхабе (https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/issues/868) говорится об обратном. Вы можете попробовать сделать какой-нибудь код на python (например кроссплатформенная библиотека pyaudio) для записи звука, а затем как-нибудь соединить это с C#

Comment: @Aarnihauta Да, я пробовал ставить NAudio, и он мне тоже писал, что ОС должна быть Windows, но уточняется, что при использовании WPF, я же использую Avalonia (Схожа с WPF), но кроссплатформерная, может NAudio воспринимает ее как WPF и поэтому выдает ошибку, но проблем не будет

Comment: Есть еще http://www.portaudio.com/, можете написать (или где-то взять) код на c/с++ для этой библиотеки, а дальше вот это https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/interop/marshalling-data-with-platform-invoke (но я не уверен, честно говоря)

Comment: Попробуйте сделать library проект под .net 6, в котором будете работать с naudio, а затем подключите к вашему проекту avalonia, мб заработает

Comment: ох уж эти шарписты...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй разобраться с `gstreamer-sharp`. gstreamer это практически стандартный движек для мультимедиа в линукс.

Принцип работы: добавляешь пайп, в пайп кидаешь autoaudiosrc, audioconvert, opusenc (или другой кодек, можно и без него, если устроит pcm) и appsink ([пример](https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer-sharp/blob/9d7f360da7e3e0b3cf16adef83778d358aa35da7/samples/BasicTutorial8.cs)) или filesink.

Дальше соединить и нажать на плей на пайпе - аудио пошло!